# is_partitioned behavior when no elements satisfy predicate

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, stl-algorithm

I was surprised to see the following code return true:

```
bool isSadPancake(char c) { return c == '-'; }

string pancakes = "+++";

bool isParitioned = is_partitioned(pancakes.begin(), pancakes.end(), isSadPancake);
```

The documentation I see online said `is_partitioned` returns true if all the elements in the range *[first, last)* that satisfy the predicate appear before all elements that don't.  In this case, no elements that satisfy the predicate appear so I expected a return value of false.  Is this expected behavior?  Where in the standard can I find more details?

Comment: Relevant reference [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.partitions).

Comment: The logical error in your thinking is that "no elements that satisfy the predicate appear" is a non-sequitur. It's not relevant; the algorithm is not concerned with "whether elements that satisfy the predicate appear".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way of seeing it is that *all* elements that satisfy the predicate do in fact appear before those that don't. All zero of them.

An even better way of thinking about it is like this: What would it mean for the sequence to *not* be partitioned? That means you should be able to find first an element that does not satisfy the predicate, followed by one that does. And you cannot find such a counterexample in your sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you clearly read the documentation it says
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_partitioned

**Return value**
true if the range [first, last) is empty or is partitioned by p. false otherwise.